# Check dates fall within range using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I'm currently working on something which requires me to check availability between two dates. My current methods aren't returning the expected result. For example, say I have the following reservations:

- 13/04/2015 to 18/04/2015
- 15/04/2015 to 20/04/2015
- 10/04/2015 to 16/04/2015

and I wish to view all reservations that are between 15/04/2015 to 16/04/2015. Visually, this might look like:

```
              15    16
      X________|_____|______X
               |X____|_____________X
X______________|____X|
               |     |
```

To get all the reservations that fall between these dates I am using:

```
public List<ReservationClientModel> GetReservationsByDateRange(int id, DateTime checkin, DateTime checkout)
    {
        var reservation = _repository.FindAllBy(x => 
            (x.StartDate >= checkin && x.EndDate <= checkout) ||
            (x.StartDate >= checkin && x.StartDate <= checkout) ||
            (x.EndDate >= checkin && x.EndDate <= checkout)),
            y => y.RoomTypeNav)
            .ToList();

        return Mapper.Map<List<ReservationClientModel>>(reservation);
    }
```

Which is using:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAllBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var set = _dbSet.AsQueryable();
        set = includes.Aggregate(set, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        return set.Where(predicate);
    }
```

This will only return the last two reservations though, and I believe this to be because it is checking for `>=` and `<=` on the dates, rather than checking that it falls within the range. I'm aware of using the SQL `BETWEEN` operator, but I was wondering if there is any way to do this using a Linq expression or from within C#? Ideally I would like to perform this as part of the EF Query as opposed to returning all reservations, then performing the operations on this list.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't the operators for your start-date and end-date need to be switched? x.StartDate >= checkin is stating that they checkin before x.StartDate (x.StartDate being larger or after (or equal to) checkin) and then for enddate x.EndDate <= checkout is saying that checkout is greater than or after (or equal to) x.EndDate. Is this your desired outcome?

Comment: @CalebB, yeah I think thats correct. It was a problem with the way I was thinking. I was trying to see if the start and end dates were inside my range, or that start date or end date individually fell within my range. It was a bit of strange approach now that I think about it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two ranges overlap if following rule is true:

```
(StartDate1 <= EndDate2) and (EndDate1 >= StartDate2)
```

By applying this rule to your code you get:

```
var reservation = _repository
    .FindAllBy(x => x.StartDate <= checkout && x.EndDate >= checkin,  
               y => y.RoomTypeNav)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Clean and simple. Easy now that I see it written down, lol. Cheers Kaspars!