# Find Date Overlapping in DataTable Using Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable having startdate and enddate columns. I want to check overlapping startdate and enddate using linq.

method input Parameters:

### ***Input DataTable***

| startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- |
| 01/Jan/2021 | 31/Jan/2021 |
| 01/Feb/2021 | 28/Feb/2021 |

**Input Parameters**

FromDate: 15/Feb/2021

ToDate:   20/Feb/2021

Expected OutPut: true

I have created a function to check for overlapping dates.

```
private bool IsDateOverlap(DateTime? FromDate, DateTime? ToDate, DataTable Table)
        {
            bool isOverlap = false;
            try
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < Table.Rows.Count; index++)
                {
                    if (index == this.RowID)
                        continue;
                    DateTime? rowFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Table.Rows[index]["startDate"]);
                    DateTime? rowToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Table.Rows[index]["endDate"]);
                    isOverlap = (FromDate <= rowToDate && rowFromDate <= ToDate);
                    if (isOverlap)
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
            return isOverlap;
        }
```

Its working fine.
I want to do it using linq. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you looking for something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517461/5174469) ?

Comment: In your LINQ statement use something like `row => row.Field<DateTime>("startDate")`. These `Convert`s aren't necessary.

Comment: @Gert Arnold There is no Linq in question.

Comment: I mean in the LINQ you write by taking the code from the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach that might help you how ever i use a custom object rather than a datatable.

```
  public static List<inputDataTable> ListOfDates = new List<inputDataTable>
        {

               new inputDataTable { startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/Jan/2021"), endDate = DateTime.Parse("31/Jan/2021"),},
               new inputDataTable { startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/Feb/2021"), endDate = DateTime.Parse("28/Feb/2021"),},

        };
  

 public static bool checkOverlapping(DateTime starDate, DateTime endDate, List<inputDataTable> storeDate)
        {
            var e = storeDate.Where(a=> (starDate >= a.startDate && starDate <= a.endDate) || (endDate >= a.startDate && starDate <= a.endDate) );
            if(e.Count() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
           
        }
```

Also you can visit these threads;
[Check dates fall within range using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653983/check-dates-fall-within-range-using-linq/29654447)

[Check One Date is falling Between Date Range-Linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232325/check-one-date-is-falling-between-date-range-linq-query)